# solr java.lang.NullPointerException on select

Tags: select, solr, nullpointerexception

I have recently started getting the error pasted below with solr-3.6 on /select queries.

I don't know of anything that changed in the config to start causing this error. I am also running a second independent solr server on the same machine, which continues to run fine and has the same configuration as the first one except for the port number.

The first one seems to be doing dataimport operations fine and updating index files as usual, but fails on select queries.

An example of a failing query (that used to run fine) is:

```
http://[machine_name]/solr/select/?q=title%3Afoo&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on
```

I also found that I get this error only when the result set is non-empty. I am stupefied. Any idea?

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /solr/select/. Reason:

null

java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.process(QueryComponent.java:398)
at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:186)
at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1376)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:365)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:260)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:399)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:928)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector$Connection.run(SocketConnector.java:228)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

I'm using the `solrconfig.xml` taken from the solr examples.

Comment: COuld you post your solrconfig.xml please? I think you have problems with the components chain while making queries. One required component is probably missing I guess.

Comment: Appended solrconfig.xml just below the original post.

Comment: I had a look at your `solrconfig.xml`. It looks messy, I guess it's the one taken from the solr examples. I suggest you to remove the parts you don't need, you'll probably end up with a really short file. Problem is that the examples contain all the possible options you can use. Anyway, with that config I was able to index a document  and retrieve it. Your component chain looks good. Did you change your schema and forgot to reindex?